# Error when printing data from database; prints multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with a local server and a mysql database and am trying to display the data in the database using PHP.

My error is that the data is not displayed once, but it is displayed multiple times.

This is my code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysqli_select_db($con,'busapp') or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bustable");
if($sql === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
{
    $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I had 2 entries in my table, I was getting data like this:

`[{Entry 1}]`, `[{Entry 1}]`, `[{Entry 2}]`

I added one more entry to see how it was going to behave, and this is what I see
`[{Entry 1}]`, `[{Entry 1}]`, `[{Entry 2}]`, 
`[{Entry 1}]`, `[{Entry 2}]`, `[{Entry 3}]`.

At 4:

```
[{Entry 1}], [{Entry 1}], [{Entry 2}],

[{Entry 1}], [{Entry 2}], [{Entry 3}],

[{Entry 1}], [{Entry 2}], [{Entry 3}], 

[{Entry 4}]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: can you try printing the data without converting them in json and see what it displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're printing the whole `$output` array each time through the loop. So the first time through the loop you have one row in the array, and print it. The next time through the loop you add the second row to the array, and then print those two rows. On the third iteration, you print all 3 rows. And so on.

You should print the array after the loop is done, not inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a newbie mistake. Accepting in 10mins